# Remove unverified Meteor users after certain time period?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm working on a Meteor app and I want to rid the app of the antiquated "Create New Account" then "Check Your Email to Verify Account" workflow.  I want users to sign up with an email (not a username) and immediately have some access to the app, a verification email will fire, and then they can verify at a later time to get full access.  So I would be calling `Accounts.createUser` immediately and always (as long as their email isn't already taken.)

How would I go about "taking out the garbage" of any email-based accounts that get created but are never verified?  Like if I wanted to delete an unverified account after 3 days for example?

The only way I can think of is to do a really long `Meteor.setTimeout` command in the `Accounts.onCreateUser` hook that would check if the accounts email is verified after three days (which is 259,200,000 ms BTW).  Is this practical?  Will it work?  Is there another method in Meteor to do something like this? That isn't dependent on user actions.  I don't want to do this when the user logs in because a user could create an account with a bad email and then never log in again, but a future user with that email would then be locked out.

Does Meteor have any type of "server rules" that would fire every so often to run checks?  Like setup some kind of nightly maintenance function/routine?  Also, is it possible to remove a `User` like this?  I was reading another article that said something about not being able to remove users through the API.  I definitely need to be able to do that because the whole point is to make that email/account available to a user that actually owns that email.

If I have to I can go to the "force verification" methodology, but I see other sites doing the above and I like it much better.  It's also way slicker on mobile.

EDIT: I was just looking at the Meteor docs and sending a "verification email" requires a userId which means you have to create a user no matter what - `Accounts.sendVerificationEmail(userId, [email])`.  So I guess no matter what a user with a bad email could get created.  So it would be nice to know how to do the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [percolatestudio:synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron):

```
meteor add percolatestudio:synced-cron
```

Then in your Javascript on the server:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {

    SyncedCron.add({
      name: 'Remove unverified users',
      schedule: function(parser) {
        // parser is a later.parse object
        return parser.text('every Wednesday at 12am');
      }, 
      job: function() {
        //TODO: implement RemoveUnverifiedUsers function
        var numUsersRemoved = RemoveUnverifiedUsers();
        return numUsersRemoved;
      }
    });

    // start the cron daemon
    SyncedCron.start();
  }
}
```

Edit #1:

The Meteor user will have an email object with verified:false in the Meteor.users collection. [This part of the meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_users) provides the following example:

```
{
  _id: "bbca5d6a-2156-41c4-89da-0329e8c99a4f",  // Meteor.userId()
  username: "cool_kid_13", // unique name
  emails: [
    // each email address can only belong to one user.
    { address: "cool@example.com", verified: true },
    { address: "another@different.com", verified: false }
  ],
  createdAt: Wed Aug 21 2013 15:16:52 GMT-0700 (PDT),
  profile: {
    // The profile is writable by the user by default.
    name: "Joe Schmoe"
  },
  services: {
    facebook: {
      id: "709050", // facebook id
      accessToken: "AAACCgdX7G2...AbV9AZDZD"
    },
    resume: {
      loginTokens: [
        { token: "97e8c205-c7e4-47c9-9bea-8e2ccc0694cd",
          when: 1349761684048 }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm really digging percolatestudio:synced-cron.  Very cool and very flexible.  Also of note, removing a user is simple server side, it's just a call to `Meteor.users.remove({_id: user._id})`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple cron with `Meteor.setInterval`.

I wouldn't advise using `Meteor.setTimeout` with the `onCreateUser` hook. This is because if you're server is restarted/has a crash/you update the code within this 3 day period the snippet won't run.

Server Side Code:

```
Meteor.setInterval(function() {
    // new Date must always be new Date()
    var three_days_ago = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (3600000*72))

    Meteor.users.find({
        createdAt: {
            $lte: three_days_ago  //Users created less than 3 days ago
        },
        'emails.0.verified': false
    }).forEach(function(user) {
        //Do action with 'user' that has not verified email for 3 days
    });
}, 3600000);
```

The above code runs every hour, checking for users that were created more than 3 days ago (72 hours) that have not yet verified their first email address.

Answer (score 1):

To mix and update the old answers (@Akshat wrote `new Date(new Date.getTime() - (3600000*72))` but it's `new Date(new Date().getTime() - (3600000*72))` ), **in a cron job way every day**

#### Install synced-cron

```
meteor add percolate:synced-cron
```

#### On server, in a cron.js

```
import { SyncedCron } from 'meteor/percolate:synced-cron';
import { deleteUnverifiedUsers } from './delete-unverifiedUsers.js';

SyncedCron.config({ log: false, utc: true });

SyncedCron.add({
  name: 'Check verified Users',
  schedule(parser) {
    //return parser.text('every 10 seconds');
    //return parser.text('every 1 hour');
    return parser.text('every 24 hours');
  },
  job() {
    deleteUnverifiedUsers();
  }
});

SyncedCron.start();
```

#### On server in the task file (here delete-unverifiedUsers.js)

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

// Set since variable in milliseconds*hours : ex 1h = 3600000*1
var one_day_ago = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (3600000*24))

Meteor.users.find({
    // condition #1: users created since variable ago
    createdAt: {
        $lte: one_day_ago,
    },
    // condition #2: who have not verified their mail
    'emails.0.verified': false
}).forEach(function(user) {
    // Delete the users who match the 2 conditions
    return Meteor.users.remove({_id: user._id})
});
```